# Header Not Showing

Tags: html, text, http-status-code-404

on my website, there should be a large question mark in the middle of the error page. It is not an image, it is in an h6 tag. it only appears (for me) when I search for it (ctrl+f on pc). It is in the code but does not appear. any help? to find the page, get a 404 error.
e.g. : [http://amosjackson.com/randomstuffsasdf](http://amosjackson.com/qwertyuiop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `position` property of `h5` is set to `relative` in your stylesheet, but should be `absolute` instead. So, it's a CSS thing that's making the question mark go outside of the viewport.

Comment: @AmosJa The h5 is placed relatively to your Body tag, which has a fixed width of 9000px, so the H5 will be placed behind those 9000px, which is far more than any regular monitor can display.